# How to use TypeScript generics to extend a library function with React's useCallback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript, react-dropzone

I am creating a component with react-dropzone. react-dropzone provides a `useDropzone()` which takes a object for arguments, e.g. `useDropzone({ onDrop })`.

[CodeSandbox example is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-keldysh-2fdtjh?file=/src/DropzoneForm.tsx)

useDropzone's type is:

```
export function useDropzone(options?: DropzoneOptions): DropzoneState;
```

DropzoneOptions are

```
export type DropzoneOptions = Pick<React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>, PropTypes> & {
  onDrop?: <T extends File>(acceptedFiles: T[], fileRejections: FileRejection[], event: DropEvent) => void;
};
```

How do I type `acceptedFiles` (instead of any) by typing the generic `T` in a useCallback?

```
  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles: any) => {
    acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
      console.log(file)
    })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add type to function inside the `useCallback`

```
const onDrop = useCallback(<T extends File>(acceptedFiles: T[]) => {
  acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
    console.log(file)
  })
}, [])
```

You also have the option to directly use the type on useCallback

```
type OnDropType = NonNullable<DropzoneOptions['onDrop']>;

const onDrop = useCallback<OnDropType>((acceptedFiles) => {
  acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
    console.log(file)
  })
}, [])
```

[`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) is needed because `useCallback` doesn't like undefined as function type.

Comment: It seems useCallback generics must follow some rule, which is that the first type param is extended.